# navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition return differently between firefox and chrome?

Tags: javascript, google-maps-api-3, geolocation

I have a snippet

```
navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(function(position) { 
        // do somehthing
});
```

but the result returned is different between chrome and firefox. the position in chrome have no adress property.

anyone can help?

Thanks

Comment: It's probably something wrong somewhere else in your code - need to see more code please.

Comment: no, i debug and find that chrome does not have the address property while firefox does. u can see this snapshot 
https://lh4.googleusercontent.com/-1clzMF9NoFE/TsIeZ5fin8I/AAAAAAAABNo/5VrlvEz2DRw/s833/x.png

Answer (score 3):

It looks like Firefox is a bit ahead of the curve with the position interface.  The standard does not currently support an address property.

[Geolocation API specifications:](http://dev.w3.org/geo/api/spec-source.html#position_interface)

> The Position interface is the container for the geolocation
>   information returned by this API. This version of the specification
>   allows one attribute of type Coordinates and a timestamp. Future
>   versions of the API may allow additional attributes that provide other
>   information about this position (e.g. street addresses).

The position object that is returned by the `getCurrentPosition()` Method contains a coordinate property with the latitude and longitude.

```
navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(function(position) { 
    var lat = position.coords.latitude;
    var lng = position.coords.longitude;        

    // do something with lat and lng
});
```

If you need the street address you are going to have to use a geocoding service (like [Google Maps Geocoder](http://code.google.com/apis/maps/documentation/javascript/reference.html#Geocoder), which is what [Firefox is using to find the address](http://www.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/geolocation/)) to look up the address.